# Should "null" ever a valid value for a property?

Tags: java

I have a key=value property, which is then written to file. If a key exists but the value is empty or null, it is saved as, key="". Now, could the literal string "null" ever be a valid property value for a key? Which got asked in my code review but I feel like it would be bad practice to treat it as valid, as the system treats empty strings as null values.

At the moment, the property is formatted as an empty string if it is null or "null"

```
if (key != null && !key.trim().isEmpty() && key.startsWith("-D")) {    
    if (value == null || value.equals("null")) {
        value = "";
}
//Other code
```

The value is appended onto a formatted key to be written to a file.

Comment: Not sure how anyone can answer this question except in more general terms since we don't know your system.

Comment: "Now, could the literal string "null" ever be a valid property value for a key? " Yes.

Comment: Who are you to decide whether someone may or may not be named "null", for instance? Remember, this world contains more than one country, each with their own naming weirdnesses.

Comment: To further that; `Null` is a perfectly valid Gaelic surname

Comment: Your Data structure is a Map??

Comment: With your code, as it is currently written, the input "null" would result in an empty value. You should limit the second if to `if(value==null)` to allow "null" as a valid value.

Comment: check my answer it might help you bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably should have been posted to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

However, whether `"null"` can be equated to `null` and whether `null` can be equated to `""` are entirely domain specific. If your application can work with that, then it can work with that. End of story.

But the concepts of `"null"`, `null` and `""` are completely different logically and you are dealing with close to code level configuration (property files are edited by people who usually understand somethind about coding). By making these equal you make life harder for you and whoever looks at your code as their cognitive load is increased by the need to understand how your chosen non-standard special cases work.

So, if you want to make good code you should never equate `"null"` to `null` or `null` to an empty string.

Why do you need to know if a key exists without a value? In the context of key-value properties it has no meaning, since if the key doesn't have a value, then the key-value pair doesn't exist. The common use cases for Java properties are as follows:

```
# Literal value
key.1=value

# Empty string
key.2=

# Null (commented out means not defined)
# key.3=
```

Comment: "property files are edited by people who usually understand something about coding" That is a very good point, my thought behind it was that if someone sets the key to "null" I make sure the value is null. But for whatever reason, a developer may just want the value to be "null"

Comment: For what it's worth, I just discovered that the Spring SPeL parser treats case 2 differently from case 3. I had an expression like `${flag.enabled:true}`. If the property exists, with no value, this results in an empty value (not "true"). If the property setting does not exist, it results in "true".

Answer (score 0):

Literal string "null" should not be considered same as null reference. That means if your system allows "null" to be valid property value, treat is as any other valid value as long as your system doesn't explicitly state otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your code logic, but NULL and empty string are different. When using a HashMap you can set NULL Key, sometimes it is helpful to use it. If you are sure that the Map you are using can't have NULL key, then there is no need to worry about it.
Also there is a difference between NULL and string value "null". depends on the nature of the object you have and again the logic you have in your code.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you have a problem with the NULL concept. With your current code, if someone enters string "null", which is different from the NULL concept, your value will be empty. Short answer: YES, literal string "null" can be a valid property, but it depends on the logic behind your project.

Answer (score 0):

value.equals("null") is exactly a value and it is not NULL.only keywork for NULL in java is "NULL". (lower case or upper case without quotes)

see this below code it might helpyou.

```
String value = "null";  // where value key work is holding string value which is "null".
```

in order to check null use the below code

```
if (value == null)
in order to check null or empty use the below code
if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) 
//where is empty check for empty string like valueX = "";
```